# add sum to tidyverse pipeline

Tags: r

I am using:

```
library(tidyverse)

tips <- data.frame(
        gender = c("female", "male", "male")
        ,smoker = c("yes", "no", "no")
        , tip = c(10, 5, 0)
     )

tips %>%
    gather(key_value, value) %>% # wide to long
    count(key_value, value) %>%
    group_by(key_value) %>%
    mutate(percentage = round(n / sum(n), 2)) %>%
    unite(key_value_pair, key_value, value, sep = "=")
```

This results in:

```r
  key_value_pair n percentage
1  gender=female 1       0.33
2    gender=male 2       0.67
3      smoker=no 2       0.67
4     smoker=yes 1       0.33
5          tip=0 1       0.33
6         tip=10 1       0.33
7          tip=5 1       0.33
```

Is there an easy way to the sum of column tip for the above example where the sum is the sum of the particular combination (e.g. gender=female there is one row thus the sum is 10, gender=male there are 2 rows thus the sum is 5). The expected result would be:

```r
  key_value_pair n percentage sum
1  gender=female 1       0.33  10
2    gender=male 2       0.67   5
3      smoker=no 2       0.67   5
4     smoker=yes 1       0.33  10
5          tip=0 1       0.33   0
6         tip=10 1       0.33  10
7          tip=5 1       0.33   5
```

Comment: I am sorry but what exactly is not clear here? I simplified it and added the expected result! The question is 100% reproducible as well.

Comment: OK I edited the question further. But TBH this should have been quite deducible/obvious from the expected result. But maybe it is not and I am missing something. I am sorry.

Comment: Thanks for realising it! Let me post an answer.

Comment: OK thanks - I have done my walk of walk of atonement - maybe you can now remove your down and close votes xxx

Comment: @cs0815 done so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some rearranging it's possible to get exactly what you want in just a few lines:

```r
tips %>% 
    mutate(tip_sum = tip, n = 1) %>% 
    gather(column, value, -tip_sum, -n) %>%
    group_by(column, value) %>% 
    summarise_if(is.numeric, sum) %>% 
    mutate(perc = round(n/sum(n), 2))

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   column [3]
  column value  tip_sum     n  perc
  <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 gender female      10     1  0.33
2 gender male         5     2  0.67
3 smoker no           5     2  0.67
4 smoker yes         10     1  0.33
5 tip    0            0     1  0.33
6 tip    10          10     1  0.33
7 tip    5            5     1  0.33
```

The only thing I don't include is `unite`, because I don't think its essential. You can add it back if needed. The column order is also a little different. Just rearrange with `select` if column order is important.

This solution also works well with other data. For example, if your data looks like this:

```r
  gender smoker tip
1 female    yes  10
2   male     no   5
3   male     no   0
4 female     no   5
5   male    yes  10
```

The above solution will return this:

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   column [3]
  column value  tip_sum     n  perc
  <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 gender female      15     2   0.4
2 gender male        15     3   0.6
3 smoker no          10     3   0.6
4 smoker yes         20     2   0.4
5 tip    0            0     1   0.2
6 tip    10          20     2   0.4
7 tip    5           10     2   0.4
```

Comment: @Sotos I've removed the reference to my answer. But the criticism stands as it is directly relevant to your answer, which produces the wrong output for any data beyond the example above. It wouldn't make sense to add it to the comments under the question as it has nothing to do with the question. I also think my answer more closely follows the OP's train of thought. It is really almost the same code, with just a couple minor modifications.

Comment: Critisism is welcomed. I dont have such issues. My problem was the comparison. Other than that, thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @Sotos thanks for pointing out that I crossed a line. I'm still learning the ropes, and SO's etiquette is occasionally a little confusing. I had seen references to other answers before, which is why I thought it would be okay. But now when I think about it, those references were usually used to clarify or point to alternatives, and not to say "go look at this better answer". Makes sense.

Comment: No problem. It's just that sometimes people do things like that in order to get more rep. You d be amazed what some people do. They treat rep like money. But I did realise that it was honest misunderstanding from your part so no worries :). Good answer too btw.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to do the sum separately and merge, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

tips <- data.frame(
        sex = c("female", "male", "male")
        , smoker = c("yes", "no", "no")
        , tip = c(10, 5, 0)
     )

tips %>%
     gather(key_value, value) %>% # wide to long
     count(key_value, value) %>%
     group_by(key_value) %>%
     mutate(percentage = round(n / sum(n), 2)) %>%
        left_join(
            tips %>%
            gather(key_value, value, - 'tip') %>%
            group_by(key_value, value) %>%
            summarise(s = sum(tip)),
            by = c('key_value', 'value')
        )
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 5
> # Groups:   key_value [?]
>   key_value value      n percentage     s
>   <chr>     <chr>  <int>      <dbl> <dbl>
> 1 gender    female     1       0.33    10
> 2 gender    male       2       0.67     5
> 3 smoker    no         2       0.67     5
> 4 smoker    yes        1       0.33    10
> 5 tip       0          1       0.33    NA
> 6 tip       10         1       0.33    NA
> 7 tip       5          1       0.33    NA
> ```

If you really need to fill the NAs with the same values as your `key_value` for `tip` then you can easily replace them (or `coalesce`) etc.

Comment: @cs0815, besides being far more verbose than necessary, this will not always produce the correct answer (assuming I've correctly understood the question). We need the sum of the tips for each key-value pair. The sum of tip=0 will always be 0, but tip=10 can be 10, 20, 30, etc., and tip=5 can be 5, 10, 15, etc. The "use coalesce" workaround won't work either as it will simply add 0, 10, and 5 to s.